# How to terminate a single async task in multiprocessing if that single async task exceeds a threshold time in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How to terminate a single async task using multiprocessing in WINDOWS if that single async task exceeds a threshold time (say, 60 seconds) in Python?

```
import multiprocessing as mp  

def compute(test_num):  
    return test_num ** 2

def main():  

    test_num_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)  
    results = [pool.apply_async(compute, args=(test_num,)) for test_num in test_num_list]

    output = [r.get() for r in results]  
    print output
```

Comment: what error does it show? i just tried to run it, and it worked for me

Comment: @ DorElias I've corrected my question. May I have the answer please?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to kill a task that has already been sent to a Pool object.

Because you control the child process, you can create your own 'watchdog' timer to make sure the process doesn't execute longer than some set amount of time. One way to do this would be to spawn a thread that waits on a conditional event with a timeout, and kills the process if the computation didn't finish in time:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys

def watchdog(e):
    finished = e.wait(timeout=60)  # returns True if Event signaled
    if not finished:
        sys.exit(-1)

def compute(test_num):
    return test_num ** 2

def time_limited_compute(test_num):  # Use this as the target of your process
    e = Event()
    Thread(target=watchdog, args=(e,)).start()

    r = compute(test_num)

    e.set()
    return r
```

Because the multiprocessing.Pool will respawn any Process that dies while working on a task, this should give you the result you're looking for.

Make sure you put a timeout on your get() call as well. As this will throw a `multiprocessing.TimeoutError` in the event it times out, you'll need to handle that:

```
def main():

    test_num_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)
    results = [pool.apply_async(time_limited_compute, args=(test_num,)) 
               for test_num in test_num_list]

    def get_or_none(r):
        try: return r.get(60)
        except mp.TimeoutError: 
            return None

    output = [get_or_none(r) for r in results]
    print output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you @MykWills. The code shows the following error when timed out (also the processes do not terminate):   File "C:\Users\darwin\Desktop\FCT_v2.31\FCT_2.35_timeout.py", line 2989, in Execute_Projects
    output = [r.get(timeout=60) for r in results]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 563, in get
    raise TimeoutError
TimeoutError. Can you please tell me why is this happening. I would really appreciate your answer!

Comment: @zaman I fixed up the code to catch the `multiprocessing.TimeoutError` that will be thrown be `get` in the event of a timeout. Just tested this on my local box and it seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991968/asynchronous-multiprocessing-with-a-worker-pool-in-python-how-to-keep-going-aft/31185697#31185697) to your question.

You can use [pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble) process Pool for that purpose.